# samuelsons rule

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, trace

I just found the [Samuelson's rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicPolynomial.html) of simplifying the computation of a characteristic polynomial.

$f(\lambda)=\lambda^n-a_1 \lambda^{n-1}+ ...+(-1)^na_n$

$a_1 = Tr(A)$

$a_n = det(A)$

$a_i$ = the sum of the i-rowed diagonal minors of the matrix A

However, I'm unsure how I extend this to a 4x4 matrix.

- Does the sum of the diagonal minors need to be in front of the $\lambda^2$ term? In that case, which coefficient does come in form of the $\lambda$ term?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: Both the $\lambda$ term and the $\lambda^2$ term will have a sum of diagonal minors as coefficients (they will be $a_2$ and $-a_3$ respectively).

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! That means that all the $a_i$ terms have the same coefficient but then alternating between positive and negative? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: No...you're dealing with different minors in each case. It may help to write out the formula in terms of just indices in the 3x3 case to see what the $\lambda$ term looks like in the 3x3 case.

Comment: Ah I see thanks a lot! I understand it now.